# Percent sign/brackets in column name Acces table: Access got confused

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 table with a percent sign in the column name (yes, I know, not recommended, but it's imported from another system).

Now Access is complaining when I use it in an INSERT query (SELECT query no problem):

```
INSERT INTO Test (Sample_Date, [WC%O2 (%)])
SELECT Wq.Sample_Date, Wq.[WC%O2 (%)] FROM Wq
```

Is there some way to escape this or should I rename my columns?

UPDATE: Maybe there is a problem with the brackets? Or both.

Answer (score 0):

I would rename the columns, even if I manage to escape the percent sign.

Comment: Sure, but I have a lot of this tables (all the same structure). And I'm just curious if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Using tables based on your SQL, an `UPDATE` statement (is not a query :) works fine for me, as does an `INSERT`. What error message are you getting?

**UPDATE** (pun intended :)

Have you sanity checked that the columns do actually exist? e.g. does this

```
SELECT Test.[WC%O2 (%)], 
       Wq.[WC%O2 (%)]
  FROM Test, Wq;
```

run without error?

Comment: The error message is: "The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: '[WC%O2 (%)]'

Comment: Yes, your query works (as said the SELECT works fine). It created the query with the Query Design grid

Comment: @waanders: any chance that the column name in table `Test` has more than one space

Comment: e.g. `[WC%O2  (%)]` rather than `[WC%O2 (%)]` ?